# Install third party POSIX Threads for Windows

Tags: windows, pthreads, posix

I have found some details about using [pthreads4w](https://github.com/jwinarske/pthreads4w) but could not find a complete example. What steps must be made in detail to install PThreads4W?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I put things together. The goal is to have **pthread** available as system library on Microsoft Windows so I can just `#include <pthread.h>` to my source code to use its functions.

The main issue is that the compiler/linker can find all parts of the library which are the header file `pthread.h`, the linkable library `pthread.lib` and its executable part `pthread.dll`. It will look at predefined directories. For the header file it will look at the environment variable `INCLUDE` or will use settings in environment variable `CL`. `INCLUDE` is only used by the buildsystem **nmake**. Builds with **Visual Studio** does ignore it. Settings in `CL` is used by the compiler so it works on both buildsystems and we will use that. For `pthread.lib` the compiler looks at the environment variable `LIB` and the executable program searches for the needed `pthread.dll` using the `Path` environment variable.

I use the PowerShell. First we have to download and install **pthreads4w** from **GitHub**. It uses `cmake` and can only be compiled with `nmake` so we have to use the Generator 'NMake Makefiles'.

```
PS> git clone https://github.com/jwinarske/pthreads4w.git
PS> cd pthreads4w
PS> cmake -S . -B build -G 'NMake Makefiles' -D BUILD_TESTING=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
PS> cmake --build build --config Debug --target install
    --- snip ---
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/bin/pthreadVCE3d.dll
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/lib/pthreadVCE3d.lib
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/bin/pthreadVSE3d.dll
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/lib/pthreadVSE3d.lib
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/bin/pthreadVC3d.dll
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/lib/pthreadVC3d.lib
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/lib/libpthreadVCE3d.lib
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/lib/libpthreadVSE3d.lib
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/lib/libpthreadVC3d.lib
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/include/_ptw32.h
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/include/pthread.h
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/include/sched.h
-- Installing: C:/Users/ingo/devel/pthreads4w/PTHREADS-BUILT/x86_64/Debug/include/semaphore.h
```

That's where you find all headers, libs and dlls. Or something clearer:

```
.\PTHREADS-BUILT\
└── x86_64
    └── Debug
        ├── bin
        │   ├── pthreadVC3d.dll
        │   ├── pthreadVCE3d.dll
        │   └── pthreadVSE3d.dll
        ├── include
        │   ├── _ptw32.h
        │   ├── pthread.h
        │   ├── sched.h
        │   └── semaphore.h
        └── lib
            ├── libpthreadVC3d.lib
            ├── libpthreadVCE3d.lib
            ├── libpthreadVSE3d.lib
            ├── pthreadVC3d.lib
            ├── pthreadVCE3d.lib
            └── pthreadVSE3d.lib
```

There are some more libraries using exeptions but we only use the default and recommended shared version **pthreadVC3d**. For details about this naming look at the README of the project.

Now we provide the generic library name `pthread.lib` with a symlink and set the environment variables.

```
PS> cd PTHREADS-BUILT\x86_64\Debug\lib\
PS> new-item -itemtype symboliclink -path . -name pthread.lib -value pthreadVC3d.lib
PS> $env:CL = "/I C:\Users\ingo\devel\pthreads4w\PTHREADS-BUILT\x86_64\Debug\include"
PS> $env:LIB += ";C:\Users\ingo\devel\pthreads4w\PTHREADS-BUILT\x86_64\Debug\lib"
PS> $env:Path += ";C:\Users\ingo\devel\pthreads4w\PTHREADS-BUILT\x86_64\Debug\bin"
```

Don't forget the plus sign and the starting semi colon. For testing it I use this simple program:

```
PS> type .\simple_pthread.cpp

#include <pthread.h>

#include <iostream>

namespace // no name, i.e. anonymous for file scope
          // this is the C++ way for decorator STATIC
{
void* start_routine(void*) {
    std::cout << "-- Hello from POSIX Thread" << std::endl;
    return 0; // calls pthread_exit()
}
} // namespace

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    int rc;
    void* retval;

    std::cout << "-- starting POSIX Thread" << std::endl;

    rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &start_routine, NULL);
    if (rc != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error! unable to create thread, rc=" << rc << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    rc = pthread_join(thread, &retval);
    if (rc != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error! Unable to join thread with rc=" << rc << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (retval != NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Error! Thread failed with retval=" << retval << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now use it (where ever you have it stored):

```
PS> cl /EHsc .\simple_pthread.cpp pthread.lib
PS> .\simple_pthread.exe
-- starting POSIX Thread
-- Hello from POSIX Thread
```